# PDO Wrapper make select where data not like "string"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
return $this->baseClass->db->SELECT("order", '*')->results();
```

The above code will return me all the data from the table, but i need pdoQuery that i can take ALL data from table where are NOT equal to 'someString'. Any ideas?

I'm using PHP PDO Class Wrapper Version 1.2 (Beta)

Comment: Do we need to start making guesses as to what the wrapper is?

Comment: Please be warned that this wrapper is supposedly [a rather harmful one](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: Best answer, @Jon Stirling.... leorik... You should, at the very least, copy and paste the `SELECT()` Method from your PDO Wrapper so it is easier for others to see what's going on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use wrong wrapper you must do like this

Example #1

`$this->baseClass->db->pdoQuery('SELECT * FROM table WHERE col != ?', array('text'))->results();`

Comment: Wow! Accepted in 8 seconds. that's probably a world record

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for